# CSV/parquet to Dynamo, small file of ~500k rows, only two columns

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am looking for a way to upload CSV/parquet data to dynamo db without having to create a data pipeline.

I have a small (12mb parquet/30mb CSV) file which consists of two columns. It gets generated daily and the dynamo table needs a full refresh each day.

At first I decided to use AWS Athena, which was very easy to setup. But for reads, its slow (each query takes 1.5 to 4 seconds). This process may be used by others in the company in the near future, so I am now seeking something quicker.

I looked into Dynamo DB's batch write item function. But it feels extremely inefficient to make about 500000/25 calls a day to update this relatively small size table.

What is a bit frustrating is that a single call using batchwriteitem has a max size of 16mb, with 400kb per row. Which is almost the size of the file itself.

I looked into perhaps sending the data as one long row, and splitting it. But I could not find such an operation. Curious if anybody has any input on this.

Comment: why not club few rows together and upload as a single entity. did you try that?

Comment: Would there be a way to break that apart once its in dynamo though? I could not find evidence of that.

Comment: is the use that you want to query every row?